# How can I move objects

Tags: html

***the Adobe Flash program, giving the effect of a coordinate walking coordinate other format can I learn html5 code.***

Comment: This is even less clear than your last question.

Comment: benim ne demek istediğimi gayet iyi anladınız.Tepkinizin nedenini anlamış değilim.

Comment: Maybe you should learn english before trying to ask questions in english. I'm not being a jackass, I'm not a native speaker neither.

Comment: http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/benim%20ne%20demek%20istedi%C4%9Fimi%20gayet%20iyi%20anlad%C4%B1n%C4%B1z.Tepkinizin%20nedenini%20anlam%C4%B1%C5%9F%20de%C4%9Filim.

Comment: @Murat, maybe you could find a site in the Turkish language that could explain things better for you.

Comment: @paul Tomblin,Turks sites, inadequate!!!! opinion that would be useful for me to meet people like you, dear.

Answer (score 4):

**[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**

```
$("div").animate()
```

**Canvas**
MDN tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial

**SVG**
 Raphael http://raphaeljs.com
 d3.js http://d3js.org

Comment: @ 3on 
 thank you very much for your interest

Comment: Are you a bot or just copy pasting ?

Comment: ** I'm human!!! I am not bot
 I do not know ilgilizce
 Even badly you want to communicate with spoken language
 I would like you to help me understand and **

Comment: I'm sorry I don't talk turkish, and I can barely understand what you post. I did what I could.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.
 do not expect to speak Turkish.
 You can make your shares to the British.
 good night ...

Comment: @3on : You get an "A" for effort.

Comment: @Beska Karma thing, if I'm good to everyone, maybe life will somehow stop being a b**** on me.